# RadioGroup CheckedChangeListener wrong index

Tags: java, android

I have a quiz type app and on each question I have an option that lets the user to flag the question.

When I open the dialog at first everything works, but if I open the dialog again causes the index increment.

For example, if I press at index 5, Result Index is 5 and then if I open the dialog again and press the index 5 again the result is 10.

```
    Dialog alert = new Dialog(this);
    alert.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    alert.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);

    RadioGroup mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) alert.findViewById(R.id.dialog_radioGroup);
    final String[] options = {
            ((RadioButton)mRadioGroup.getChildAt(0)).getText().toString(),
            ((RadioButton)mRadioGroup.getChildAt(1)).getText().toString(),
            ((RadioButton)mRadioGroup.getChildAt(2)).getText().toString(),
            ((RadioButton)mRadioGroup.getChildAt(3)).getText().toString(),
            ((RadioButton)mRadioGroup.getChildAt(4)).getText().toString(),
    };

    mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
           sendToServer = options[i];
        }
    });
    alert.show();
```

It works first time, but if I try again I always get a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you confuse the params in [RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html)
It suppose to `onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)` where you confuse the `checkedId` as index `i` in your code above.

You can check the `checkedId` like below

```
mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    if (group.getChildAt(i).getId() == checkedId) {
                        sendToServer = options[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks i learned a new thing today :), i thought that the i was the index and not the id thanks alot

Comment: No need to loop over children. Simple `findViewById(checkedId)` works.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my issue it's not pretty but it works, still i don't understand why the index is
auto-incrementing on the listener

when the user clicks send, i run this check

```
if(((RadioButton) mRadioGroup.getChildAt(0)).isChecked()){
    index = 0;
}else if(((RadioButton) mRadioGroup.getChildAt(1)).isChecked()){
    index = 1;
}else if(((RadioButton) mRadioGroup.getChildAt(2)).isChecked()){
    index = 2;
}else if(((RadioButton) mRadioGroup.getChildAt(3)).isChecked()){
    index = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that the OnCheckedChange method passes the id of the view, not the index. You will have to change your code to use a SparseIntArray instead of an array, and set each value at its id, not index. Or else you can work with the `indexOfChild` function .